# Are declared arrow functions lambda expressions in Dart?

Tags: dart, lambda

It is my understanding that a lambda function is a function that can be nameless. Wikipedia suggests that

```
var sqr = (x) => x * x;
print(sqr(5));
```

(where `var` is the same as `dynamic Function(dynamic)`), and

```
print(((x) => x * x)(5));
```

are both possible ways to write a lambda expression in Dart.

On some tutorials I read that code similar to

```
dynamic sqr(dynamic x) => x * x;
print(sqr(5));
```

is also considered to be a lambda expression, because it uses the arrow sign. It is my understanding however, that this is ***not*** a lambda expression, because this function will always need to be defined with a name. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic sqr(dynamic x) => x * x;` isn't an anonymous function because it has an identifier.

`var sqr = (x) => x * x;` is a lambda because `(x)` doesn't have an identifier.

`=>` is just shorthand for `{ return something; }` and it doesn't necessarily mean you're writing an anonymous function. For example:

`var sqr = (x){ return x * x;};` is still an anonymous function.